# gitlab-rails dbconsole command returns 'primary' database not configured for 'production'

Tags: docker, gitlab

Our Gitlab is version 14.x and is running in a docker container.

I believe I have found the solution to a problem we are experiencing with **Gitlab Community Edition**. Solution is here >>> https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html#reset-runner-registration-tokens

However, I'm stuck at the first hurdle. Running `gitlab-rails dbconsole` causes a log stream output. And checking the detail it appears as though this line is outlining the culprit.

**`db_config': 'primary' database is not configured for 'production'**

I have checked the correct database.yml file and can see the ONLY db environment is in fact the production one.

I have tried running `gitlab-rails dbconsole -e production` too. Same problem output.

Any guidance would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

A workaround may be to run `gitlab-rails dbconsole --db main`

I created an issue for this: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/358603

Answer (score 2):

Solution to this problem for me at lease was to run this command, as root.

`gitlab-psql -d gitlabhq_production`

Comment: This will work (and starts up quicker than the rails dbconsole). There is a subtle difference though: it connects as the PostgreSQL administrator, rather than as the application DB user. Most of the time this does not matter, but if you are testing a weird bug, then it may be important to connect through the Rails wrapper.